# Windows 7 64 bits taking hours to load. Even the bootable Windows CD is behaving on the same way

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I bought a wd5000aakx hard drive. It is one of that models that came with Advanced Format Drive.

I did a clean install of Windows 7. Everything was working fine, and loading fast.
But one time, after comming back from the suspended mode, after typing the password, it crashed, and I needed to press the reset button.

Another time, after a long time of inactivity time the motinor was turnned off. I pressed a key to turn it on again, and after this the problems started. Everything was completly slow.

I needed to press reset again...

After this Windows is taking a lot of minutes to show the backgroudn with the cursor. I did't have patiance yet to wait for the menus to be loaded (I'm not sure if it will really load).

To increase the problem, I tried to boot from the windows DVD again... And it is completly slow too. I felt asleep waiting for the installation program to start. When I clicked install, everything was completly slow.

So, I think this maybe a hardware problem.

Ubuntu is loading fast from a pendrive.

---

My HD cable was on the "orange" sata port. (I think its sata II. Is it?)...
If I put it on a red port, that I think it's SATA I, windows laads the error check, and the message saying "Trying to repair" remains for minutes and minutes. I did't wait it to be completed also, because I dont know if it will end sometime.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to connect that hard drive on other computer with THE SAME cable, then with ANOTHER cable, and find out the results of your tests. It COULD be an error coming from your cable... Also, try loading NOT the Windows installation DVD, but the RECOVERY disc...

Answer (score 1):

[Run the hard drive manufacturers diagnostics on the hard drive](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=606&sid=30&lang=en)

.

Comment: and check the cables the drive units are using.